# Is this query safe?

Tags: mongodb

I have a index `{s:1}` on collection k like:

Data in k likes :

`{ s:"aaa"} , 
{s:"bbb"} , 
{s:""}`

Is it safe to use `{s:{$gt:""}}` to find out every item that the length of s greater than 0 ?

Comment: Can anyone show me how mongodb build string-based index , what's the order of strings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's "safe" based on the fact:

- Any non-empty string is greater than empty string in lexicographical order.
- The index works properly so performance should be ok.

To test if index works properly, you can execute

```
db.collectionName.find({s: {$gt: ""}}).explain()
```

When seeing `"cursor" : "BtreeCursor s_1"`, it means the index worked.

However, do you consider to modify your application logic and remove `s` field when it's empty?

- `db.test.find({s: {$exists: false}}).hint({s: 1})` can be used in this query. It is more nature than `$gt`.
- You can benefit from [MongoDB sparse index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#sparse-indexes) in performance. Especially when most of your data are with empty `s`.

Comment: well but `{s: {$exists: true}}` would not use index

Comment: and i'm not sure is the lexicographical order used in mongodb when it create string based index.

Comment: Updated about `$exists`, need an extra hint.

Answer (score 0):

Using $ne would probably be more appropriate

ie "not equals"

Comment: Yes, but you can combine that with a null check like `{s: {$ne: "", $ne: null}}`.